# CATIA Macro Scripting - Expand Single Tree Node

Tags: vba, catia

Is it possible to expand a single node in the tree all levels, using macro code. I see that you can expand all nodes, but I don't want to do that. Also, I see you can expand selected, but I don't want the user to have to make a choice, additionally I can't even get this StartCommand working properly. Just wondering if it's possible to expand a single node using only macro code, and if so, HOW? I'm using V5 R22.

The node has been selected already, Here is my code using SendKeys...

`CATIA.StartCommand ("Expand Selection")
AppActivate "CATIA V5"
SendKeys "{UP}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"`

This has no effect on the Expand Selection dialog

Comment: V5? V6? 3DEx? Expand how many levels? There are several known limitations depending on what are you using....

I would delete nyself what I wrote as answer but I can't see how to do it :-)

Comment: V5 R22. Expand all levels on a single node, not the entire tree. Is that enough info?

Comment: Yes. First ,you need to search the node by name and select (in your code), then use CATIA.StartCommand("Expand Selection"), then use SendKeys "{TAB how many times is need it}" to be sure you will write the level need it (also with SendKeys) , use again SendKeys "TAB" to go to OK button, hit Enter with SendKeys again. As far as I know, there is no other way to do it in V5. Usually, I'm using just first part of what I described here, search and select the node, run Expand Selection and let the user do the rest of the job, SendKeys is not one of my preferences.

Comment: OK, I guess I better find another way. SendKeys will not work at all. For some reason, the SendKeys have no effect on the dialog. I'm guessing that Catia is lacking any proper way of manipulating the tree, where I don't see that SendKeys are a good method of doing this even if it did work. Anyway, thanks for the response, but I have tried this method and was not able to get anywhere with it.